# Negative identity matrix is not a single commutator

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that the negative identity matrix $-I_2$ in $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ is not a single commutator, i.e. there does not exist $A, B \in \text{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ such that $-I_2 = [A,B] = ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$.

A hint I was given is to perform a contradiction proof by analyzing the eigenvalues of such matrices. If we had $[A,B] = -I_2$, then we have $AB = -BA$, i.e. $-A = B^{-1}AB$. From here, I notice that if $Av = \lambda v$ for some eigenvector $v \in \mathbb{C}^2$ and eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, then $-Av = -\lambda v$, so  $B^{-1}ABv = -\lambda v$, i.e. $ABv = -\lambda Bv$. In other words, $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ with eigenvector $Bv$.

But since $\det(A) = 1$, we have that $\lambda(-\lambda) = \lambda^2 = 1$, so the eigenvalues of $A$ must be $\pm i$. The same process shows that the eigenvalues of $B$ are also $\pm i$. From here, I'm not sure where to go to produce a contradiction. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not sound right. Let $A=\pmatrix{i&0\\ 0&-i}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&i\\ i&0}$. Then $A,B\in SL_2(\mathbb C)$ and $A^2=B^2=-I_2$. Therefore
$$
ABA^{-1}B^{-1}
=AB(-A)(-B)
=(AB)^2
=\left[\pmatrix{i&0\\ 0&-i}\pmatrix{0&i\\ i&0}\right]^2
=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}^2
=-I_2.
$$

It is true, however, that $-I_2$ is not a commutator in $SL_2(\color{red}{\mathbb R})$.

Suppose the contrary. Then $A$ is similar to $-A$, $B$ is similar to $-B$, and $AB$ is similar to $BA=-AB$. Therefore the spectra of $A,B$ and $AB$ over $\mathbb C$ are all equal to $\{i,-i\}$. By a change of basis, let $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$. Since $B$ is traceless, we may write $B=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&-a}$. As $AB$ is also traceless, we must have $b=c$. Hence $1=\det(B)=-(a^2+b^2)$, which is impossible.